# Out of memory error, while reading large CSV file (millions of lines) in java

Tags: java, csv

I am getting out of memory error while reading large CSV file in java. How can I deal with this problem. I increased the heap size, I also tried using BufferedReader, but still the same problem persist. Here is my code

```
public class CsvParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "data.csv");
            Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, " ", true);
            System.out.println(values);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseCsv(Reader reader, String separator, boolean hasHeader)
            throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        int numLines = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(separator);
                    if (tokens != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
                            if (numLines == 0) {
                                columnNames.add(hasHeader ? tokens[i] : ("row_" + i));
                            } else {
                                List<String> column = values.get(columnNames.get(i));
                                if (column == null) {
                                    column = new LinkedList<String>();
                                }
                                column.add(tokens[i]);
                                values.put(columnNames.get(i), column);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ++numLines;
                }
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forget to throw away some information.  If you cannot spot yourself why, this would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a profiler like jvisualvm in the JDK

Comment: Do you need to keep every single line in memory ? Cant you just process one at a time ?

Comment: What do you want with the content of the csv file?

Comment: I want to do partition on that file. Example: if I have type attribute(column), and I have n different values for type(attribute), then I need to do n partitions.

Comment: Change default memory. Define new JVM size

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to build your custom parser. Your implementation will probably not be fast or flexible enough to handle all corner cases.

You should try [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) CSV parser to handle that for you. It comes with a built in CSV parser, [which is the fastest parser among any other for java](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison). Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

It is extremely memory efficient and we built a custom parser on top of its architecture to parse a 42GB MySQL dump file, with more than 1 billion rows, [for this project](https://github.com/uniVocity/load-mysql-dump)

Here's a quick and diry example of how to use uniVocity-parsers CSV parser:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(yourFile));
```

Comment: Does it work with non-csv files like plaintext files for example?

Comment: CSV is just plain text, can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to parse comma's etc, I just want to assign all lines in a text file to a `List<String>` using a line break to determine the end of a line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load everything in memory, you need memory.

By loading the complete file in memory you wil always have the risk of OutOfMemory errors.

If you really need all data always accessible you can start thinking of using a database. An embedded database like sqlite is easy to integrate, little overhead and is able to manage the data on disk. This way no mather how large your files are, you will not have a memory issue.

Comment: I dont have access to any kind of database, any other solution

Comment: @AnoopDobhal - Sometimes you can't do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is a limited resource so if you want to deal with large files you need to have an approach of dealing with portions of it. I suggest taking a look at RandomAccessFile and MappedByteBuffer of the NIO library. Is the best solution i can think of your problem. You can access the data of the files without loading it entirely to the memory. take a look at [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/01/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/) link for a quick head start.

Answer (score 1):

it's not the `csv-file` itself, which fills the memory up, it's the `values` variable which contains the "copy" of the file itself + certain object overhead.

I also saw, that you are "transposing" your original csv-file. That means, that, as other posters already mentioned, you HAVE to use some file-based storage to keep the memory fingerprint at minimum, or add more RAM to you computer and hope that it helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming: *C* columns, *L* lines, *B* characters per field, and 64-bit JVM:

1. The data from the CSV file has roughly *C×L×B* characters, so it takes *(32 + 24  +2×B)C×L×B* bytes of memory to store all the values as strings. Consider interning them if the values repeat, or storing as UTF-8 byte arrays in *(24 + B)C×L×B* bytes. Or, if you feel confident, combine the two and implement an interning pool for byte arrays.
2. `LinkedList` takes 40 bytes per node, so it's another *40×C×L* bytes. `ArrayList`s are smaller, they take only 8 bytes per node, and also faster in almost every use case, including yours.

You need at least *(96 + 2×B)×L×C* bytes of memory, plus a bit of overhead. If you switch to ArrayLists and byte arrays, you should need about *(32 + B)×L×C* plus overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading it all into memory, try doing a bit at a time.

Something like a [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) or a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) should help you manage this.